Пожалуйста, помогите найти и исправить ошибки в следующих предложениях (ТЕМА: УПОТРЕБЛЕНИЕ ОДНОРОДНЫХ ЧЛЕНОВ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ)
Отредактировал, чтобы остались предложения,
которые я так и не смог исправить (понять, где ошибки). Буду признателен за разъяснения 1. Наиболее интересные номера, лучшие активные участники фестиваля будут премированы и включены в ансамбль песни и пляски. 2. Пора это понять всем руководителям, и отчёты представлять вовремя, и подходить к ним со всей серьёзностью. 4. Ветер хоть и обдавал лицо и тело прохладой, но обжигал щёки и шею. 5. Иванов был высокий, худощавый человек средних лет, с усами и бритым выдающимся подбородком и выпуклыми мутными глазами. 8. Комитет установил руководство и контроль за работой нашей организации.

Вы выполните, а мы проверим. Укажите, какие трудности у вас возникли, что не поняли, мы объясним. А задание за вас никто выполнять не станет.

Можете, пожалуйста,  подсказать, где ошибки в предложениях № 1,2,4,5,8. Честное слово, отыскал все что можно, никак не могу понять. Предложение №5 вообще взято из "Анны Карениной" (заменена только фамилия). Но задание упражнения именно ИСПРАВИТЬ ОШИБКИ, но как исправить то, чего нет?

Если внимательно прочитаете эти предложения, все поймёте. В третьем предложении обратите внимание на родовое слово: "посуды" а затем внимательно прочитайте все предложение.

Я знаю, как исправить 3,6,7 и 9 предложения. Мне нужна помощь именно с 1,2,4,5,8. Потому что либо там нет ошибок, либо они очень хорошо спрятаны и моих знаний для их определения недостаточно.  Поэтому и прошу помощи. У меня очень много заданий, а я застрял только на этом.

4 предложение верно.

...что следует представлять отчеты вовремя и...

В предложении про Иванова ошибки не вижу.

Благодарю вас, Серж, за помощь! Понял, где ошибки, взял на вооружение.

Рад был помочь.

Антон, упражнение из какого учебника?

Здравствуйте! Простите за поздний ответ. Учебник – Русский язык,  11 класс, Узбекистан (2018).  Составители Г. РАХМАТУЛЛАЕВА, Т.КЕЛЬДИЕВ.
